# How can I delete just one parameter with urlsearchparams.delete()?

Tags: javascript

So I have an app which displays movies with Movie API and multiple buttons, which show movies of particular genre. So when I click on multiple of such buttons, they all add together in the query, like in the example below:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&sort_by=popularity.desc&with_genres=99&with_genres=80&with_genres=35
```

So when I click on one of those genre buttons second time, I want to remove particular genre from url. I tried to do it like this:

```
function genreChoose(e){
        let genres = {
            Action: 28,
            Adventure: 12,
            Animation: 16,
            Comedy: 35,
            Crime: 80,
            Documentary: 99,
            Drama: 18,
            Family: 10751,
            Fantasy: 14,
            History: 36,
            Horror: 27,
            Music: 10402,
            Mystery: 9648,
            Romance: 10749,
            Science_Fiction: 878,
            TV_Movie: 10770,
            Thriller: 53,
            War: 10752,
            Western: 37
        };
        let url = new URL(lastUrl);
        if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')){
            url.searchParams.append('with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
        }else if(e.target.classList.contains('active')){
            e.target.classList.remove('active');
            url.searchParams.delete('with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
            
        }
        
        fetchURL(url);
        console.log(url);
    }
```

So if a button is active and is clicked, it should remove 'active' class and also remove particular genre from the url, but instead, it becomes like this:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&sort_by=popularity.desc
```

So instead it just removes all 'with_genres' params, but I'm trying to find a way to delete just one of 'with_genres' parameter.

Edit: so I used T.J. Crowder's example, I added a function to remove value:

```
let url = new URL(lastUrl);
        params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));
        console.log(params.toString());
        if(e.target.classList.contains('active')){
            removeValue(params, 'with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
        }else if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')){
            url.searchParams.append('with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
        }
        fetchURL(url);
    }
```

But it doesn't really remove anything, maybe I should implement it with promises?

Edit 2:
So I added a snippet of code, it doesn't display movie blocks sadly, but you can see how url changes when I click genre buttons. So when I click on it, it adds a genre, but when I unclick it, it doesn't remove anything, tho it shows console.log that genre is removed, so I guess it has to do something with removeValue function, but I can't figure out what.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const API_KEY = 'api_key=73b31f15b44a93f52789c751c34a5d7d';
  const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  const API_URL = '/discover/movie?' + API_KEY + '&sort_by=popularity.desc';
  const url = BASE_URL + API_URL;
  const movie_container = document.getElementById('movie_container');
  const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
  const next = document.getElementById('next');
  const ulTag = document.querySelectorAll('.numb');
  const liTag = document.querySelector('li');
  const genres = document.querySelectorAll('.genre');

  var lastUrl = '';
  fetchURL(url);
  
  trendingMovies = movies =>{
        movie_container.innerHTML = '';

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
            title = movie.title;

            const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
            movieEl.classList.add('movie');

            movieEl.innerHTML = 
            `<img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
                `
            movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);

        });
    }


  function fetchURL(url) {
    lastUrl = url;
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        trendingMovies(data.results);
        
      })
  }

  
  const removeValue = (params, key, valueToRemove) => {
        const values = params.getAll(key);
        if (values.length) {
            params.delete(key);
            console.log('param deleted', params.toString());
            for (const value of values) {
                if (value !== valueToRemove) {
                    params.append(key, value);
                    console.log('params appended:', params.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return params; 
    };

    genres.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            genreChoose(e);
            if(e.target.classList.contains('active')){
                e.target.classList.remove('active');
            }else if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')){
                e.target.classList.toggle('active');
            }
            
    }))


    function genreChoose(e){
        let genres = {
            Action: 28,
            Adventure: 12,
            Animation: 16,
            Comedy: 35,
            Crime: 80,
            Documentary: 99,
            Drama: 18,
            Family: 10751,
            Fantasy: 14,
            History: 36,
            Horror: 27,
            Music: 10402,
            Mystery: 9648,
            Romance: 10749,
            Science_Fiction: 878,
            TV_Movie: 10770,
            Thriller: 53,
            War: 10752,
            Western: 37
        };
        let url = new URL(lastUrl);
        params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));
         if(e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active')){
            removeValue(params, 'with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]); 
            console.log('remove genre');
        }else if(!e.target.classList.contains('active')){
            url.searchParams.append('with_genres', genres[e.target.innerText]);
            console.log('add genre');
        } 
        
        fetchURL(url);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --primary-color: #39445a;
  --secondary-color: rgb(34, 24, 24);
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.app h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: #39445a;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.movie_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.movie {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  background-color: #282c34;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.movie .movie_title {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
}

.genres {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
}

.genres .genre {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 3px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 0.850rem;
  margin: 2px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.genres .genre.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h1>discover movies</h1>
  <div class="genres">
    <div class="genre">action</div>
    <div class="genre">adventure</div>
    <div class="genre">animation</div>
    <div class="genre">comedy</div>
    <div class="genre">crime</div>
    <div class="genre">documentary</div>
    <div class="genre">drama</div>
    <div class="genre">family</div>
    <div class="genre">fantasy</div>
    <div class="genre">history</div>
    <div class="genre">horror</div>
    <div class="genre">music</div>
    <div class="genre">mystery</div>
    <div class="genre">romance</div>
    <div class="genre">science fiction</div>
    <div class="genre">TV movie</div>
    <div class="genre">thriller</div>
    <div class="genre">war</div>
    <div class="genre">western</div>
  </div>
  <div class="movie_container" id="movie_container">
    <div class="movie">
      <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
      <span class="movie_title">the dark knight</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your current approach is much too complicated

Instead of recording the previous URL, getting the category picked and removing that one category from the list of categories in the parameter, you can simply construct the parameter again by selecting every element which has the `genre` *and* `active` class in the `genreChoose` function, looping through each element and appending the category code to the `URLSearchParams`.

To do this, we'll need to toggle the `active` class before calling `genreChoose`, so the category element would have the `active` class when we select the element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const API_KEY = 'api_key=73b31f15b44a93f52789c751c34a5d7d';
  const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  const API_URL = '/discover/movie?' + API_KEY + '&sort_by=popularity.desc';
  const url = BASE_URL + API_URL;
  const movie_container = document.getElementById('movie_container');
  const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
  const next = document.getElementById('next');
  const ulTag = document.querySelectorAll('.numb');
  const liTag = document.querySelector('li');
  const genres = document.querySelectorAll('.genre');


  fetchURL(url);

  trendingMovies = movies => {
    movie_container.innerHTML = '';

    movies.forEach(movie => {
      img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
      title = movie.title;

      const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
      movieEl.classList.add('movie');

      movieEl.innerHTML =
        `<img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
                `
      movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);

    });
  }


  function fetchURL(url) {
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        trendingMovies(data.results);

      })
  }


  const removeValue = (params, key, valueToRemove) => {
    const values = params.getAll(key);
    if (values.length) {
      params.delete(key);
      console.log('param deleted', params.toString());
      for (const value of values) {
        if (value !== valueToRemove) {
          params.append(key, value);
          console.log('params appended:', params.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    return params;
  };

  genres.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.target.classList.remove('active');
    } else if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
      e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    }
    genreChoose(e);
  }))


  function genreChoose(e) {
    let genres = {
      Action: 28,
      Adventure: 12,
      Animation: 16,
      Comedy: 35,
      Crime: 80,
      Documentary: 99,
      Drama: 18,
      Family: 10751,
      Fantasy: 14,
      History: 36,
      Horror: 27,
      Music: 10402,
      Mystery: 9648,
      Romance: 10749,
      Science_Fiction: 878,
      TV_Movie: 10770,
      Thriller: 53,
      War: 10752,
      Western: 37
    };
    params = new URLSearchParams('');
    document.querySelectorAll('.genre.active').forEach(f => params.append('with_genres', genres[f.innerText]))
    fetchURL(url + ([...params].length > 0 ? '&' : '') + params.toString());
  }
}
```

```css
body{margin:0;padding:0;--primary-color:#39445a;--secondary-color:rgb(34,24,24);background-color:var(--primary-color)}.app{display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:100%;min-height:100vh;background-color:var(--secondary-color)}.app h1{font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;color:#39445a;font-size:2em;font-weight:900}.movie_container{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:center}.movie{cursor:pointer;display:flex;flex-direction:column;width:200px;padding:5px;margin:5px 15px;background-color:#282c34;border-radius:10px;font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif}.movie .movie_title{font-family:"Montserrat",sans-serif;text-transform:uppercase;color:#fff;font-size:1em;font-weight:900;text-align:center}.genres{display:flex;justify-content:center;flex-wrap:wrap;margin:10px}.genres .genre{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.87);display:flex;align-items:center;text-transform:capitalize;cursor:pointer;background-color:#fff;line-height:3px;border-radius:10px;padding:5px 15px;font-size:0.850rem;margin:2px;font-family:'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif}.genres .genre.active{color:#fff;background-color:#3f51b5}
```

```html
<div class=app><h1>discover movies</h1><div class=genres><div class=genre>action</div><div class=genre>adventure</div><div class=genre>animation</div><div class=genre>comedy</div><div class=genre>crime</div><div class=genre>documentary</div><div class=genre>drama</div><div class=genre>family</div><div class=genre>fantasy</div><div class=genre>history</div><div class=genre>horror</div><div class=genre>music</div><div class=genre>mystery</div><div class=genre>romance</div><div class=genre>science fiction</div><div class=genre>TV movie</div><div class=genre>thriller</div><div class=genre>war</div><div class=genre>western</div></div><div class=movie_container id=movie_container><div class=movie><img src=img/dark_knight.jpg> <span class=movie_title>the dark knight</span></div></div>
```

<sup>The HTML and CSS have been minified. They have not been altered.</sup>

#### Explanation

The following 2 lines of code are all that are needed to implement this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.genre.active').forEach(f => params.append('with_genres', genres[f.innerText]))
fetchURL(url + ([...params].length > 0 ? '&' : '') + params.toString());
```

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will select every element which matches the CSS selector passed as a parameter, and return the selected elements as a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). The selector in this case is `'.genre.active'`, which selects all elements with the `genre` *and* `active` class (elements with the `genre` class and not the `active` class and vice/versa will not be selected).

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) accepts a callback function, which will be called for each item in the list, with the element passed as the parameter (in this case, `f`). Inside the loop, we use [`URLSearchParams.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) to append the category code to the `with_genres` parameter.

The ternary operator (`([...params].length > 0 ? '&' : '')`) is used to add a `&` between the URL and the GET parameters only if there are parameters. If there are no parameters, having a trailing `&` is redundant.

Comment: hi! i've implemented your function and it works well, url changes but for some reason divs with movies don't get updated in trendingMovies function(), might it be because fetchUrl() is a callback function in your example?

Comment: @Carl I've tested it, and a response is being returned. It appears to be a problem in the `trendingMovies` function. You're assigning `IMG_URL + movie.poster_path` to `img`, but you didn't define `IMG_URL`.

Comment: ah, i actually have IMG_URL defined, i just didn't include it in a snippet. But before implementing the function divs changed just alright, but now they don't, even if genre in url changes, maybe i should rewrite fetchUrl function another way?

Comment: @Carl Does `trendingMovies` work when `IMG_URL` is defined?

Comment: it does, you see, when it calls fetchUrl() as you defined, it just shows default movies sorted by popularity, but without genres, so everytime it just shows movies without genres, even if url has with_genres param

Comment: @Carl Looks like I was using the `with_genre` parameter. It should have been `with_genres`. Try the updated answer.

Comment: i see, i didn't notice that typo myself, now it works, thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a one-method way to do it. You have to:

- Get all the current values ([`getAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/getAll))
- Remove the key entirely
- Add back the values you want to keep

Here's an example:

```js
const removeValue = (params, key, valueToRemove) => {
    const values = params.getAll(key);
    if (values.length) {
        params.delete(key);
        for (const value of values) {
            // BEWARE, remember the values will have been
            // covnerted to string
            if (value !== valueToRemove) {
                params.append(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return params; // For chaining if desired
};

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append("test", "a");
params.append("test", "b");
params.append("test", "c");
console.log(params.toString());
removeValue(params, "test", "b");
console.log(params.toString());
```

Comment: hi! i tried to implement your function but for some reason it doesn't work
i wrote console.log inside of it to see if it even starts and it logs into console, but the function itself doesn't remove url params

Comment: @Carl - As you can see with the live example above, the code does work, so it sounds like some error applying it to what you're doing.

Comment: i edited my original question, so i'm guessing the problem might be with if..else, maybe i should use promises for that problem?

Comment: @Carl - Yes, it's probably something with the condition you're using in the `if`, but from what's in the question it seems right. One thing is that you typically want `currentTarget`, not `target`, but often it doesn't matter. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: hi! i added a snippet of code in my original question, so as you can see, it adds genres but doesn't remove them for some reason

Comment: @Carl - It's a typo, you're looking for the `actve` class, not the `active` class.

Comment: oh sorry, yes, i had that typo but i corrected it after adding a snippet, and it didn't really change anything, removeValue() still wasn't working

Comment: @Carl - You're also calling `removeValue(params, 'sort_by', 'popularity.desc');`, not using the genre. Please take a careful look at the code and debug it, the `removeValue` function I've given you works.

Comment: ahh, i'm not really experienced with snippets, you're right, i added removeValue(params, 'sort_by', 'popularity.desc') just to check out if it works with other parameters. I edited now and as you can see in the snippet, it doesn't work with genres either

Comment: @Carl - Did you take note of my comment in the code about types and how the value you get back will be converted to string? You have to allow for that if your genre values are numbers. Again, please do debugging.

Comment: ok, i've added some console logs for debugging into functions(in the original snippet), so as you can see, removeValue removes the param but then it adds it back for some reason. And i've also converted genres to strings, but it didn't really change it